# Why tinymce inserts &nbsp; on copy pasting the html?

Tags: html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using the latest version of TinyMce,

And when I copy paste some html content from wikipedia, it actually inserts lots of `&nbsp;` which are not present in the source.

Example, I select the following string from wikipedia:

```
trained professionals and paraprofessionals coming
```

From this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_care

And It has the following source code:

```
trained <a href="/wiki/Professional" title="Professional">professionals</a> and <a href="/wiki/Paraprofessional" title="Paraprofessional">paraprofessionals</a> coming
```

Note: As we see there are no noob-spaces (`&nbsp;`).

Then when I paste it to the tinymce it produces the following html:

```
<h3 style="background-image: none; margin: 0px 0px 0.3em; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 0.17em; border-bottom-style: none; font-size: 17px; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 19.200000762939453px;"><span style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;">trained&nbsp;</span><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0b0080; background-image: none; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;" title="Professional" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional">professionals</a><span style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;">&nbsp;and&nbsp;</span><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0b0080; background-image: none; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;" title="Paraprofessional" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprofessional">paraprofessionals</a><span style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;">&nbsp;coming</span></h3>
```

Or, as a plain text it would look like this:

```
trained&nbsp;professionals&nbsp;and&nbsp;paraprofessionals&nbsp;coming together
```

Which actually breaks my layout because it all goes in one line (as one word).

Any ideas why it does it and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you copy some content from websites, it copies the style of the text also. So all you need to do is you should paste the copied content into notepad first, then from there you can again copy the same content and then paste in tinymce.

```
(Notepad gives you the plain content without any inline style)
```

Comment: I want to keep the html though. The only problem is these '&nbsp;' - they don't allow for line breaks and so breaks my layout.

Comment: Then you need to remove it manually. That is what I use to follow

Comment: Maybe yeah, I need to process them manually, it actually allows for line breaks, that is possible thanks to tags, the problem occurs when I strip tags... I would better work out that part indeed.

Answer (score 0):

First Copy the content in any place ex (Wikipedia, google, etc). Past the all content in **Notepad** file. The total back links and spaces are deleted after copy the notepad content past the **Tiny MCE Editor**. It is the better way to use this type.

Comment: That would also remove the html... I'll keep it in mind though if in case I won't need any styles.

Answer (score 0):

When copying content from a web page, use View Source in a browser and copy the relevant part from the source and then insert it in “raw mode” (source mode, HTML mode, whatever it is called—I presume TinyMce has got such a mode; if not, get a better tool). To make this easier, in Firefox, you can paint an area and then right-click and select the option of viewing the source of the selection. (Well this might need an add-on like DOM Inspector, I’m not sure.)

It’s possible that TinyMce converts spaces to something else even in “raw” mode. I have seen such things happen in a CMS (spuriously changing normal spaces to no-break spaces), with no explanation found, and I hope I won’t need to use such a CMS ever again.

Comment: Well the problem is with classes, if you copy paste the source - it wouldn't work due to use of classes.

Comment: @Anonymous, how would the class attributes vanish if you copy & paste the HTML source? (If the document has been manipulated with client-side JavaScript, you may need to use e.g. Firefox with Web Developer extension and use View Source → View Generated Source in its toolbar.)